# Access satellite view of other planets in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been searching far and wide for anything about how to access the satellite view of other planets (Mars, Venus, etc) in Google Maps API, but to no avail. I'm guessing this probably (still) isn't available but thought I'd ask here in case someone may know something about this topic.

As you may know, satellite view on other planets is available on Google Maps, when you zoom out of Earth's satellite view you can click on other planets on the side.

Cheers!

Comment: You need access to the imagery: [Google Example of Moon "Satellite View"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image)

Comment: oh, thanks! do you know maybe where I can find the image links for all the planets?

Comment: I don't know that there is a comprehensive list.  You could try searching.  A search for [satellite map of mars](https://www.google.com/search?q=satellite+map+of+mars&oq=satellite+map+of+mars&aqs=edge..69i57j69i64.10305j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gave me this: https://www.google.com/mars/about.html, which has a reference to http://www.mars.asu.edu/data/